# Why do we connect to our instance through IP address (ssh) instead of using instance id?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Why we are connecting our instance through IP address(ssh) instead of using Instance ID?

Answer (score 3):

If you're connecting using `SSH` or `RDP` to an instance then this will need to be connectable via a method that can be resolved, this would be either a hostname (mapped to the server IP address) or IP address.

If you want to use the DNS option can either use a hostname for the instance ip that is provided or setup a hostname in your DNS if you want to have a more memorable name.

This could all be automated by using [CloudWatch events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/automating_with_cloudwatch_events.html) upon any instance being created to setup a DNS hostname for your instance.

If you want to connect using your instance ID you will need to look at using an AWS solution to connect.

This solution would be [Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html) which would allow you to connect using either console or CLI.

Comment: You can use these services but it will be programmatically accessing :)

Comment: No problem have a great day :D

Answer (score 1):

Instance id is just an AWS-specific  identifier of an instance resource.

Instance id is **not routable** over internet. To to connect to your instance over internet you have to use IP addresses.

If you don't want to use plain IP address you can use instance **public DNS** of the form:

```
ec2-<ip-address-of-instance>.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Alternatively, you can setup even more user friendly name (e.g. my.instance.com) through Route53:

- [Routing traffic to an Amazon EC2 instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html)